# sliding transition animatio between two web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, slider

for example i have few webpage

how can i click the link in `1.html` to `2.html`

then `1.html` slides to left and `2.html` loada and slide from `right`?

just like this effect:

https://delicious.com/join

and the github project as well

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings

there have no browser refresh blink

and the `URL` also changed.

is it using `jquery`?

I must use `mvc php framework` or `rails` to build the `site`?

how can I create some `webpage` like this?

any `open source project` or example `code` for that?

Answer (score 2):

If what your asking is how to do the animation, then JQuery was the one responsible for it.

You can check this link for reference :

[Downloads](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/)
[Demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/)

Or you could try another search in the internet , just type "Fancy Sliding Forms"

Actually it all depends on you web designer/developer on how to implement that Jquery. Just read the docs.

God Speed!

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I'm looking for transit between different webpage,the url must be changed too

Comment: You can try to check the code of that plugin which was posted on the first link by the author. coz I think instead of having it slide to another element which was initially hidden you can try to configure it and replace it with something like url. I am not really sure coz I haven't tested it yet and I am not a fan of sliding fancy forms (sorry ^^). But I will try to do something later about it if its possible. And maybe do a bit more research coz it might not work tho .

Answer (score 1):

Recently the challenge for me was to develop lightweight web applications, so I resorted to using minimal of jQuery because when viewed in mobile, the smooth behaviour was not guaranteed. So I chose hardware accelerated css transitions.
You can place the contents of web pages in two divs and dynamically add and remove classes to see this effect.

```
/* CSS */
.page-one {
  width: 100%;  
  -webkit-transform : translateX(0px);
  height:100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  color : #6B6B77;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page-one.invisible {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.page-one,
body {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.page-two {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}

.page-two.visible {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
}

.page-two,
body {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```